# Interpreting linear regression diagnostic plots correctly in R

Tags: r, regression, linear-model, assumptions

I've been trying to build a linear regression model over ~30,000 data points (sample size) and have been trying to diagnose whether the model assumptions for it are met based on this link: http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/39-regression-model-diagnostics/161-linear-regression-assumptions-and-diagnostics-in-r-essentials/

(I have seen several posts about assumptions for linear regression but I wanted help with interpreting my particular plots since those posts and the online resources have not provided me enough examples to be 100% sure I am verifying this correctly.)

I generated the four diagnostic graphs (not the ones below) as mentioned in the link and the original model violated all the assumptions based on those graphs. After applying various transformations to the predictors and outcome variables, I ended up with the following four graphs and they still seem to the violating the linearity and homogeneity assumptions and there seem to be several outliers that I'm not sure how to handle. I don't think I can apply any more transformations to the data so I wanted to ask: am I interpreting these graphs correctly in that linear regression is **not suitable for my analysis**? (I am planning to use quantile regression if that is true.)

[image: diagnostic plots for linear regression]

Comment: Can you say more about your situation, your data, & your goals?  What are your data?  Are they bounded?  (They sure look like they are...)  What is the point of this model?  Etc.

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica Yes! The goal is at a very high abstract level to study what features of social media posts about a specific topic are associated with them being engaged with more. Each data point corresponds to a social media post; the features are various textual features or related to the metadata of posts and the outcome variable represents spread (continuous). About a third of the predictors are bounded, a few are binary, and the rest are unbounded continuous variables. Let me know if any more information would be helpful!

Comment: What is your Y variable? It appears to be bounded.

Comment: Did you try using the DHARMa plots? They are very useful. See here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DHARMa/vignettes/DHARMa.html

Comment: "After applying various transformations to the [...] outcome variables" What is the outcome variable? How do the plots look like without transforming it?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to describe the outcome variable. The outcome is not bounded.

Comment: I will check out the DHARMa plots too